# Problems with sql query return

Tags: sql, oracle

Friends, good afternoon! I have the following problem, I use the oracle developed database, and I have a procedure, in a part of this procedure I perform a validation that returns a repeated person's name and write a log to the user informing what happened.

However, at the user's request, he asked me to add a new field to this log called pgtoVlrBruto = which means gross payment amount. I have a table called procInter, but I can't make a code that I can adapt within the query, I have no idea how I would get this field. Could someone guide me please?

```
controlExec: = 'GENERATE LOG MESSAGE - 1.';
    IF codProcess IS NOT NULL and codProcess <> 0 THEN
        qtdExists: = 0;
        BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT (*)
            INTO qty
            FROM (SELECT PI.COD_INTER, PI.PGVLRGROSS FROM PROC_INTER PI
            INNER JOIN PROCESS P ON P.COD_PROCESS = PI.COD_PROCESS
            WHERE P.COD_PROCESS = codProcess) TB
            WHERE TB.COD_INTER = codInterested (Variable assigned at the beginning of the procedure.);


            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    qtdExists: = 0;
        END;

        IF qtyExists> 0 THEN

        --Part of the query that I programmed that would help me, but I can't adapt it in the query above the procedure.

        --SELECT PI.PGVLRBRUTO
        --INTO pgVlrGROSS
        --FROM PROC_INTER PI
        --WHERE PI.cod_process = codprocess
        --and PI.COD_INTERESSADO = codInterested 
        --and pi.cod_sep = SEP;
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: People here are more helpful when they see your whole attempt and tells you why it fails and how to fix. Will you consider putting an initial attempt to merge?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Oracle.